# Vipassana meditation with samadhi

Tags: theravada

In vipassana meditation either samadhi or insight  comes as the  vehicle .When samadhi comes as a vehicle it's called Samanthayanika vipassana .In Samanthayanika meditation how yogi see the impermanence suffering and no self?

Comment: Think about it. How can one see anicca, dukkha, anatta when observing concepts that are stable, satisfying and experienced as self?

Comment: @user13579 Samanthayanika meditation can not be the samadhi used in satipatthana that cultivates  vipassana?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is wrong to say that either insight (*panna*) or concetration (*samadhi*) comes through *Vipassana*. They both come through *Vipassana*, they both aid each other in their "coming through" and further growth. Of course, it is relativly easier to develop *samadhi* as compared to *panna*; nonetheless *samadhi* is perfected only when one has *panna* and *panna* cannot be perfected without having perfected *samadhi*. 
It is unclear what you mean when you say 'comes as a vehicle'. But if I were to take vehicle as that which carries you over the river of samsar- then 'vehicle' is vipassana. Concentration and Insight both go in hand in hand. A yogi who has perfected *samadhi* has more chances of perfecting panna, and therefore, is closer to Nirvana; than a yogi who is yet to perfect *samadhi* (for perfection of *panna* without perfection of *samadhi* is not possible).

DO note that these are not the only two things to be perfected. These are only two *Paramitas*. There are more.

Since the vehicle is Vipasssana only, one 'sees' the three marks of existence (*anicca* (impermanence), *anatta* (no-self), *dukhha*(suffering)) as anyone else would see-through insight build on a foundation of *samadhi* and other perfections (*paramitas*).

Comment: Great answer! I believe the questioner was referring to the two vehicles model that posits one vehicle as being A) one who practices first Samatha and then Vipassana, and B) one who practices Vipassana and then Samatha. I agree that they arise and assist each other on the Path, and must both be developed in tandem for true progress. Some modes of practice however might stress one or the other. For example, first gaining Ekagatta and then using this calm, wizened mind to look at the Three Characteristics.

Comment: @SunWuKong Yes! I very much agree that there are traditions that stress one over the other. That is good, because everyone begins at a different point. Thus, for people who think they need to work on samadhi, can go for vehicle A. Likewise, people who think they need to work on panna[pali] (prajna[sanskrit]), can go for school B.